# Not able to find Class Loader in java

Tags: java, classloader

i am running following code in My Eclipse...

```
package foo;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassLoader loader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(loader.getResource("foo/Test.class"));
    }
}
```

But iam getting o/p as **null** on console.

Help me..

Comment: Code looks fine and give correct output. is this independant class or you are using this in some method or with other code ?.

Comment: I have developed this class under one of mine application package

Comment: may be check path in `getResource` argument is correct or not ?

Comment: I have to ask - have you really tried this exact code or is this only an example to illustrate your problem? AFAIK this should work in 100%. Try it in empty project.

Comment: @Reimus there were no errors in my project at the time of running this class.And i am running this class as:-Run as=>Java Application...

Comment: @PavelHoral yes i have tried running this code in eclipse..

Comment: have you already tried to modify your resource path a bit - like `loader.getResource("/foo/Test.class");`? At least eclipse find it that way for me. But ok, I'm using maven and therefore the files are located in a jar or in the /src/main/resources/ sub-directory which is added to the classpath ...

Comment: @PavelHoral thanks for ur ans..I tried this code in empty project and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to also find out where the classloader is going to find the resource. The following code *worked for me* ***in a blank project***.

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) Test.class.getClassLoader();

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(loader.getURLs()));

            System.out.println(loader.getResource("foo/Test.class"));
        }
}
```

- Make sure that there are *no errors* in workspace.
- See if the file exists in the `Navigator` view.
- Try cleaning the project once.